# jQuery Mobile Plugin with Day and Time, Not Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to find a decent jQuery Mobile plugin for choosing a day and time. I don't need the date. I just want to be able to select:

1. **Day:** Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
2. **Hour:** 1-12
3. **Minute:** 00, 15, 30, 45
4. **Period:** AM, PM

I know there's stuff out there like http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/, but is there anything that just has the day and time? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is this one that I found. I hope it works for you. http://jonthornton.github.com/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: there is also this one http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime i think you can customize it to just select days. but i am not sure.

Comment: actually there is a custom mode for DateBox2. you could probably use that as well.